# Дан массив с числами. Переберите его циклом и запишите в новый массив только положительные из чисел

Tags: javascript, массивы

не могу понять как

```js
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let arr2 = [];
    for(let elem of arr) {
        if (elem % 2 === 2) {
            arr2.push(arr);
        }
    }
    console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: А вы точно знаете, что такое положительные числа?

Comment: Я только учусь, пытаюсь разобраться, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Положительные числа, это все числа больше нуля. Четные числа это все числа, какие при делении на 2 будут без остатка. При делению по модулю на 2, никогда не будет остаток 2. Возможно `elem % 2 === 2` заменив на `elem % 2 === 0` решит Вашу проблему

Comment: Я тормоз невнимательный ))) нужно же было на ноль делить. Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: А вы уверены что сможете на ноль поделить? Математика вот не смогла...

Comment: let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let arr2 = [];
for( let elem of arr) {
 if (elem % 2 === 0) {
  arr2.push(elem);
 }
}
console.log(arr2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего Вы ошибка в вопросе.
Положительные числа, это все числа больше нуля.
Четные числа это все числа, какие при делении на 2 будут без остатка.

Насчет кода:
При делению по модулю на 2, никогда не будет остаток 2. Всегда остаток будет меньше на 1 от делителя. Возможно `elem % 2 === 2` заменив на `elem % 2 === 0` решит Вашу проблему

Comment: Я уже выше написал что невнимательность привела к ошибке, на 0 нужно было. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1,2,4,-1,7,11,76, -2,];
let arr1 = [];

for (elem of arr) {
    if (elem > 0) {
        arr1.push(elem);
    }
}
console.log(arr1) // выведет [1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 76]
```

Comment: если бы вы изучили комментарии к вопросу и ответ, который автор принял в качестве решения, то вы бы поняли, что автору требовалось найти четные числа

Comment: При ответах на старые вопросы следует также проверить существующие ответы/комментарии.